# how to apply distinct and group by in django or in postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, group-by, distinct-values, distinct-on

table production

| code | part | qty | process_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 22 | 12 | 10 |
| 2 | 22 | 15 | 10 |
| 1 | 21 | 10 | 12 |
| 1 | 22 | 12 | 12 |

I have to extract data like based on process, every process has multiple part but I can't take every part's data, so that have to distinct on code for getting process wise summation of qty.
how to get data like this in postgresql or in django

| process_id | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 27 |
| 12 | 12 |

I tried in this way

```
Production.objects.values('process').distinct('code').annotate(total_qty=Sum('quantity'))
```

Comment: what's filter criteria? `Q`?

Comment: It isn't enough to give example output, you also have to explain the logic behind it.

Comment: that's for extract some records like above table's example @HemalPatel

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets your desired result, but from your snippet I'm not sure this is the logic you had in mind. If you add more detail I can refine the answer.

```
SELECT process_id, SUM(qty) qty
FROM production
WHERE part=22
GROUP BY process_id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but a minor issue, I can not define the part in the query that's why I am declaring distinct on code

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the logic you are after. I think that you want only one of the records for each unique combination of code and process_id, but which record do you want to keep? Always the one with the highest part number?

Comment: You get my point but not with highest part number. I want record of process wise sum of qty using combination of distinct code_id and process_id - @Simon Notley

Comment: I still don't get what you are after. I can't see any way of purely grouping the data (as opposed to filtering some of it out like I did with `part=22`) that gets your example output. If you are just grouping (into non-overlapping groups) and summing the sum of your new qty column must be the same as the original one, and in your example it isn't.